# Is there a way to layer an image in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have a report header which contains a text box filled with a background color as a "bar" design element. We simply want to add our logo on top of the bar (our logo looks like the letter 'A').

The expected result would be the logo on top of the bar, showing the bar background color in the white space of the logo (see image). This is the behavior we see in programs such as PowerPoint.

Correct rendering in PDF is required.

[image: BarWithLogo]

Comment: Make your Logo a .png.. transparent background.. should do the trick.. I think

Comment: The issue is when you export, the format may not allow overlapping - hence that warning during deployment. If you have issues in a PDF or other format, you can capture the logo over the line and make a new image file. Of course, you wouldn't be able to change the bar color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can layer images, they will get moved when rendered.

The ways I have done this in the past were to either...

1. Simply have the header as one big image
2. If I needed text in the header too I would split the header into two parts. In your case have an image on the right side that is basically what is inside the bounding box in your sample image but extending all the way to the right so it includes the right end of the grey box. Then, on the left side, have a textbox filled with the same colour and then simply put your text in that.

I've done the seconds option with a footer and it worked well, the only thing I had to do was same my images at 600 dpi so they rendered well in most formats.

Comment: We have text in the header bar that varies with each report. We've tried both approaches you list. #1 means we'd need a new image for each report. For #2, we have issues trying to line up the image with right side of bar with the main bar in the PDF rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Since transparency is not working well when exporting to PDF(black background) use snipping tool to cut a portion of the logo with the bar and save it without transparency.

[image]

For the bar instead of using a textbox, use a line (or more because of the 20pt limit) which allows overlapping with the appropriate color and size

You can also place a textbox on the top of the line(bar) for your titles

The result would look like(the color difference won't be visible in your implementation):

[image]

Export to PDF should work fine

[image]